# How do I reset Component Metadata field every time when component is re-opened?

Tags: cme, sdl-tridion, gui-extensions

I have updated the logic to clear the field during display start event.
Note: Updated my logic in readonly.js GUI extension

```
if($display)
{
   $evt.addEventHandler($display,start,ResetMetadataField)
}
Function ResetMetadataField()
{
  //code goes here
   var fieldBuilder = view.properties.fieldBuilder;
   var metadataTab = GetMetadataTab()
   if(metadataTab)
   {
     var fieldbuilder = GetMetadataFieldBuilder();
    //logic goes here to reset the metadata field
   }
}
```

But this code triggers during Save event as well. I need to reset the field only when component is re-opened but not on Save.

I am unable to differentiate between item re-open and other events like save,check-in..etc
Is there a way to achieve the functionality?

Comment: What are the conditions under which $display is set to true. Is it reset to false before the onSave event is triggered! Have you tried/checked different events to trigger your code off rather than just a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the event system subscription. You probably need to subscribe to a specific event and not just run code according to a preset parameter.

This may well help as a starter: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/intro-to-the-event-system